# SSH remote - display echo on local terminal

Tags: shell-script, ssh, echo, sshpass

The following is a part of my script where I want to `echo` some text to the local terminal if the condition fails in ssh.

```
/usr/bin/sshpass -p $PASSWORD /usr/bin/ssh -t  -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" root@$IP -p $PORT '
    cd $PATH;
    [ ! -d temp ] && mkdir temp;
    for new_file in '${NEW_FILE[@]}'
    do
        [  -f $new_file ] && mv -f $new_file temp/$new_file-'$DATE'
        DOWNLOAD=$(wget --no-check-certificate '$URL'/$new_file > /dev/null 2>&1)
        if [ '$?' -ne '0' ]; then
            mv temp/$new_file-'$DATE' '$PATH'/$new_file
            echo "$new_file download failed! please check and re-run the script"
        else
            chmod +x $new_file
        fi
    done;'
```

except `echo` remaining functionality works well ...

Let me know is it possible to `echo` from `ssh` to local terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To selectively display an individual command as well as its output, you can use something like

```
sh -vc 'echo \"Some text\"'
```

although the nested quoting can start getting on your nerves pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

`ssh -t`

From the man page:

```
     -t      Force pseudo-terminal allocation.  This can be used to execute 
arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. 
when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t options force tty allocation, even if
ssh has no local tty.
```